# assigning a string to another string

Tags: c

Why this code is not running? Why str1 is not assigned to str2 ?? I know i have an option of using strcpy but i wish to know the reason why this is not working??

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char str1[]="hello";
char str2[10];
str2=str1;
printf("%s",str2);
return 0;
}
```

Whereas if I use pointers than it works like here..

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
(
char *s="good morning";
char *q;
q=s;
while(*q!='\0')
{
printf("%c",*q);
q++;
}
return 0;
}
```

This works.
Now the string has been copied via pointers so why such difference??

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char *s in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do

`strcpy (str2, str1)`

you need to copy each element of the `str1`  to `str2` character by character.

What you are doing is to attempt assign the address of the string in `str1` assign to the array var `str2` which is not allowed. Static arrays couldn't be used to be assigned values.

Even if you had `char *str2;` and then `str2 = str1` although your code would work, but in such a case the string is not copied, instead the address of the string in `str1` is copied in `str2` so now dereferencing `str2` will point to the string

Also note that when you copy string into a `char *str2` always allocate enough memory before copy.
one possibility is:

```
str2 = malloc (sizeof (char) * (strlen (str1) + 1));
strcpy (str2, str1);
```

Comment: `strlen` of memory is one byte too small, oops

Answer (score 1):

`str2` is a static array. You can't just reassign it like a pointer.

As for your pointer example, `q=s` reassigns `q` to point to the same space that `s` is pointing to. However, the pointer reassignment does **not** copy the value.

For static arrays, use `strcpy()` to copy the value. For pointers, use `strdup()`.

Answer (score 0):

`str2` and `str1` refers to the address of their first elments
so assignment of arrays is not done in this way
use either `str[]` to assign char by char
or use inbuilt `strcpy`

Answer (score 0):

You may also use strdup() which allocates exact amount of space needed to store a copy.

Comment: Is this function found in Windows? I think it is only for POSIX-compliant operating systems. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In C you can only assign objects that have *type*; and in C a string is not a data type.  Instead it is a convention - the convention being that strings are represented by null-terminated character arrays; and because arrays are not considered as types, neither are strings.

In your second code fragment, you have simply made `q` point to `s`; this is not a *copy* of the string at `s`, but merely a copy of the pointer 's'.  They both refer to the same data in memory.  So if for example you changed the string at 's', and then printed the string at 'q', you will see that the data at 'q' has also changed.  More directly if you did `printf( "s:%p, q:%p" (void*)s, (void*)q ) ;`  you will see that they both hold the same pointer value.